# json parse in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following (snippet) variable:

```
var txt = {
        'start': {
                 'name':'Call start',
                 'data': {'next':'start/e3fe40'},
                 'id':'start',
                 'type':'standard---start'
        },
        'e3fe40': {
                'name':'Menu',
                'data':  {'next':'end/asd3rg'},
                'id':'e3fe40'
         }
};
```

I need to parse through the JSON and get info from the 'e3fe40' branch (without knowing how its going to be called.

Here's what I have:

```
var nxt = txt.start.data.next.substr(6,10); <-- works
console.log(nxt);                           <-- works
console.log(txt.start.data.next);           <-- works
console.log(txt.nxt.name);                  <-- nxt should contain 'e3fe40'
```

So, how do I go down a branch? 
txt.nxt.name won't work, txt.{nxt}.name won't work, etc....

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: That isn't JSON. It is a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: Also the word for what you're doing isn't "parse", if we're picking nits. :-)  You need the `[ ]` operator.

Comment: You're always going to struggle if you don't know the structure of your incoming data. All you can do is loop over the keys and try to identify what you want that way, but this is far from ideal.

Comment: txt.nxt should be txt.e3fe40 .. I was trying to substitute e3fe40 with nxt as variable, but dont know how

Comment: Quentin: the js object literal is initially json received from another app -- i'm posting like this to shorten the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var key = txt.start.data.next.substr(6);
console.log(txt[key].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `nxt = "e3fe40"` you get the value by doing.

`txt[nxt].name`

Different ways of accessing the values,

`txt.e3fe40.name`
`txt['e3fe40'].name` and one shown above.

`txt.nxt.name` is wrong. Because nxt is not a key in the Javascript object,

Answer (score 0):

If You debug code by using debugging tool and put this code I think it will solve your problem

```
alert(txt.e3fe40.name);
```